# Скрыть расширение у файлов .php NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

Сайт состоит из страниц *page.php*

Требуется что бы файл page.php открывался по адресу page, и так все остальные файлы с соответствующим расширением.

Пробовал вот так,

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
}
```

В таком случае главная страница *index.php* работает только по пути *site.com/index*

А по site.com/ идет ошибка *404*

Answer (score 1):

Собственно решил вопрос, прописал rewrite для каждой страницы. Пример:

```html
rewrite ^/news /news.php;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
               index index.html index.htm index.php; 
               try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          fastcgi_params;
        }

        location @rewrite {
               rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
        }
```

Comment: Подскажите, как я могу применить данный rewrite:
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
Ко всем файлам кроме index.php, это решило бы мою проблему